# ObjectiveC and substringToIndex. Issue with dot

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C and am having a odd problem with substringToIndex.

Background:
The code is part of a function that deletes the last character from the display of a calculator. I need to be able to flag when a dot is deleted

My code is:

```
NSString *currentDisplay = self.display.text;
NSString *lastChar = [currentDisplay substringToIndex: 1];
NSLog(@"lastChar -->%@<--",lastChar);
```

The problem is:
Variable currentDisplay is a numeric value, for example "123.45". When the "." (dot) is the character to be deleted, so variable lastChar is should be ".", the log shows a random number, normally the last characted deleted.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You're substringing, not deleting characters.  So "the last character deleted" is meaningless.  (And you should call the variable "firstChar", not "lastChar", since you're getting the first character in the string.)

Comment: holy crap I am pointing the first char. I should not work over the weekend. Thanks

Comment: the deletion happens later on in the same function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to tell if the last character is a "dot", use

```
if ([currentDisplay characterAtIndex:currentDisplay.length - 1] == '.') ....
```

Comment: +1 better! (as subtringToIndex creates a new string objet for you, while this doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
BOOL flagIfDotIsDeleted = NO;
unichar leftmostChar = [currentDisplay characterAtIndex: currentDisplay.length - 1];
if (leftmostChar == '.')
{
    flagIfDotIsDeleted = YES;
    currentDisplay = [currentDisplay substringToIndex: currentDisplay.length - 2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler, if you want to know if the last character is a dot...

```
if([currentDisplay hasSuffix:@"."])
```